# Trying to extract city data of city lights location?

Tags: data, google-maps, extract

Here is a website:
http://geodesy.net/webmaps/milpitas/gedit2/gedit.htm?map=base

I believe they are using Google Map API and Fusion Table(deprecated 2016).

I just wanted to extract the data to a text format.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the source of the site you linked to, you can see they send a query off to an [address](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201bfAXmQoyNEl8jA6hivwd78iQ2iJfmj3OmRQWol0%20WHERE%20MapName%20=%20%27base%27&key=AIzaSyDPnHmRyjIXaiWOWK-F-KPvA8IS5tGc00o&callback=jQuery1900041197332874478354_1516060146850&_=1516060146851), and this returns IDs of four Google Fusion Tables (column 3 in the rows array of the result). Three of them work, see below:

- [Easement boundaries](https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1AzCngWgdgmZCudEX-c6P55F-mZEh9c7CW61fHk0#map:id=3)
- [Street Lights](https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1u3TMPbn2blt8ClFDpYSIJkW6mB8W5RSmCr1QZh0#rows:id=1)
- [Hydrants](https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1JMwzQ4k8Kfr1yn-sGc3ex6_qZ-pX20WqWIO6GJA#map:id=3)

Please ensure that you use the data under the license that the city releases the data under. The fact that you can access the data doesn't mean that it's freely available!